# Keep getting this error "Unexpected character ( ) at position 1."

Tags: java, json

I'm having this issue where I'm keep getting this wierd error when I run this simple program at commandline

Here's the Json file

`{"count":"21740"}`

Here's the code

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class EarthQuake {

private static final String filePath = "data.json";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // read the json file
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

        // get a String from the JSON object
        String count =  (String) jsonObject.get("count");
        System.out.println("The count is: " + count);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

But I always get this error

```
"C:\>java -classpath .;json-simple-1.1.1.jar test
Unexpected character ( ) at position 1.
        at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
        at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
        at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
        at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
        at test.main(test.java:22)"
```

I've validated the json file at http://jsonlint.com/

I don't know what I've done wrong here, please help!

Comment: Is there some invisible character at the beginning of the file?

Comment: no, that's all in the file

Comment: Please upload the file on a public file sharing service so we can check if there's anything wrong with the file. I know you say it's okay, but who knows.

Comment: You can do what @Pimgd said or you can print the file from within Java:
        List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));
        for (String str : list) {
            System.out.println("[" + str + "]");
        }

Comment: @Jesper The character it's complaining about is a space rather than some other invisible character, on the assumption that the exception has been accurately copy/pasted.

Comment: You should be able to step through this with a debugger, and stop it within the `yylex` method to see what's happening.

Comment: Are you sure you are running your code with the correct file?

Answer (score 1):

I created a file and pasted `{"count":"21740"}` in that file and called it test.json. I was able to run the code without an error.

But to debug your issue, can you run your code with the json string passed to the parser directly like below;

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse("{\"count\":\"21740\"}");
```

Comment: cool, this worked. So what could have happened to my original pass-in of the FileReader object?

Comment: I suggest create a new file and type the valu in and save it as json. See if it works.